# django running in docker container: accessing static folder inside inlinecss

Tags: django, static, django-inlinecss

I have moved a django 1.8.6 project in a docker container that is using django-inlinecss==0.1.2 to format emails.

I have my static folder defined in the setting.py:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

MEDIA_ROOT = "/srv/media/"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
```

and this is my template:

```
{% load static %}
{% load inlinecss %}
{% load email_table %}

{% inlinecss "css/email.css" %}

{% block content %}
{% block preamble %}{% endblock preamble %}

{% block table %}{% email_table object_list %}{% endblock table %}

{% block postamble %}{% endblock postamble %}

{% endblock content %}
{% endinlinecss %}
```

If I run my project i get the following error:

[image]

I believe that the inlinecss is not finding my static file (BUT I AM NOT SURE THIS IS THE PROBLEM). I have tried the following with no success:

```
{% inlinecss "/static/css/email.css" %}
and
{% inlinecss "static/css/email.css" %}
```

in other parts of my code I successfully access static using:

```
"{% static 'js/all.min.js' %}"
```

but inside a inlinecss I cannot use this syntax:

```
{% inlinecss {% static 'static/css/email.css' %} %}
```

because of the nested {% %}. Any help is immensely appreciated.

Comment: Did your project work with `django-inlinecss` before moving it to a docker container?

Comment: Hi Danoram. Yes, my code worked before moving it to a docker container

Comment: Might be a good idea to include your inlcude your Dockerfile  or docker-compose.yml file